# Reset the css class applied on the calendar cell

Tags: javascript, angular-bootstrap-calendar

I am using [angular-bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar#documentation) and wanted to change  the color of the cell when i click on any cell in the month view. I am able to change the color using 
`on-timespan-click="timespanClicked(calendarDate, calendarCell)"`

HTML:

```
<mwl-calendar events="events" 
                view="calendarView" 
                view-title="calendarTitle" 
                view-date="viewDate" 
                on-event-click="eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
                on-event-times-changed="eventTimesChanged(calendarEvent); calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
                day-view-start="06:00" 
                day-view-end="22:59" day-view-split="30" 
                cell-auto-open-disabled="true" 
                on-timespan-click="timespanClicked(calendarDate, calendarCell)"
                cell-modifier="cellModifier(calendarCell)">
    </mwl-calendar>
```

and in JS applying `cell.cssClass = 'freeze-cell';`

JS:

```
    $scope.timespanClicked = function (date, cell) {

        cell.cssClass = 'freeze-cell';
    }
```

Here, the problem is I want to reset the css-class applied when I click on any other cell but I am not able to do so.

Thanks,
Suvojit